# I can't get the height of my HTML element set correctly with CSS

Tags: html, css, overflow

My CSS:

```
        .reviewRow 
        {    
            clear:both;
            padding-top:0;
            margin-top:0;
        }
        .reviewBlock 
        {
         float:left;
         height:100%;
         padding-top:0;
         margin-top:0;
         border-top: 1px solid #444; 
         border-left: 1px solid #444;
        }
        .reviewCaption
         {
             font: normal normal normal 6pt verdana;padding-left:0.03in;
         }
        .reviewText 
        {
            font: normal normal normal 8pt verdana;  
            height:20px; 
        }
```

My HTML:

```
<body>
<div style="HEIGHT: 30px" class=reviewRow>
    <div style="WIDTH: 125px" class=reviewBlock>
        <div id=reviewBeneficiaryType class=reviewText>This text is too big to fit inside a 30px height cell, so I want it to get bigger.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

The above HTML is excepted from a web page I'm having trouble with.  It is dynamically generated, so the text inside may be short or long.  Normally, I would expect that this will render a box 30 pixels tall with the text inside, unless the text is too big, in which case the box will expand to fit the text.

The problem is that when this HTML appears within another page, the text "spills out" of the box.  I don't understand what the problem is.  To make matters more complicated, if I remove the "height" style, it will actually make the box much taller.

I have looked at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow).  It clearly says that by default, the value of CSS "overflow" is "visible", in which case the text "may spill out", but under no circumstances do I want scrollbars to appear.

I have tried modifying the "position" CSS of the containing elements, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

What could be causing the problem here?

**Update** I have found what seems to be causing the problem!  It's the doctype declaration!  If I remove the doctype declaration from the page that this is excerpted from, it will render fine!  By why?

Comment: Why .reviewText has height: 20px? If you remove the heights it will be height:auto by default. You just need to set the width of the reviewBlock and you are clear to go.
http://codepen.io/joe/pen/rAKqh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the problem is that the DOCTYPE declaration is missing from one of the pages.  If I use the same DOCTYPE declaration on both pages, then the CSS seems to be interpreted in exactly the same way.

As for how to write the CSS just right, that's going to be a separate question if I need further assistance.

Thanks for the help!  I've upvoted all the answers I've received.

Answer (score 2):

Try to give `min-height:20px;max-height:400px;` to `.reviewText`

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying height to your div, if the text gets more obviously it's going to spill out of the container like a bottle of water can;t be poured in a small size glass, so you need `overflow: scroll;` which you don't want to use either you've to make your `height: auto;` which will increase the box size accordingly to the text it contains with `min-height: 30px;`..Positioning the element here won't help you..You don't want scrolls, you don't need your container to be auto-resized than what you actually need?

And if you want your text to be something like

```
------------------------------------------
| This is a pretty long long long long...|
------------------------------------------
```

Than try this

```
text-overflow:ellipsis;
```

Comment: I think you're on to something.

I tried setting height to 'auto', and suddenly the div grew to about 1000 pixels tall.  This appears to be about the same height as one of the containing DIVs (which is a fixed height).  I think that this containing DIV has something to do with the problem.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon Height must be getting inherited

Comment: Okay, here's something else.  I tried removing all css height properties from this HTML.  This results in the box expanding to contain the text, but borders all being messed up and misaligned.  The issue here is that there are a number of DIVs on the real page this was excerpted from.  There are several of them within each DIV decorated with the 'reviewRow' class.

Comment: @DanielAllenLangdon the border's must be messing up because you are using floats and you need to clear them, use `overflow: hidden;` in `.reviewRow`

Comment: Well that was all, not able to figure out what you exactly want, post your comment here, will reply u nxt mrning ;)

Answer (score 1):

if you generally see **normalise.css** or **reset.css** they set the height of html element to 100%.. Doing the same will do the trick.

```
html{
height:100% /* auto will also do */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SwCKU/    ..check this fiddle.